# Android Data Binding: Why doesn't passing in variable to ViewStubs work like include layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

With Android data binding it is possible to set a variable on a an included layout like so (from the documentation):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <include layout="@layout/name"
           bind:user="@{user}"/>
       <include layout="@layout/contact"
           bind:user="@{user}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I've tried doing the same thing to pass in variables when using a `ViewStub`, but it doesn't work. Why don't `ViewStub`s work like include layouts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ViewStub`s are called out as being different in the [Data Binding Library documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#viewstubs).

> **ViewStubs**
>
> ViewStubs are a little different from normal Views. They start off invisible and when they either are made visible or are explicitly told to inflate, they replace themselves in the layout by inflating another layout.
>
> Because the ViewStub essentially disappears from the View hierarchy, the View in the binding object must also disappear to allow collection. Because the Views are final, a ViewStubProxy object takes the place of the ViewStub, giving the developer access to the ViewStub when it exists and also access to the inflated View hierarchy when the ViewStub has been inflated.
>
> When inflating another layout, a binding must be established for the new layout. Therefore, the ViewStubProxy must listen to the ViewStub's ViewStub.OnInflateListener and establish the binding at that time. Since only one can exist, the ViewStubProxy allows the developer to set an OnInflateListener on it that it will call after establishing the binding.

Comment: Yes, it is very different, but why doesn't it/can't it work like an included layout?

Comment: As stated: "Because the ViewStub essentially disappears from the View hierarchy, the View in the binding object must also disappear to allow collection." I think that it is the disappearing act that makes it impossible to keep data bindings in a straightforward way. I think that  `ViewStubProxy` may give you a way to pass in variables. I do see, however, what you mean: `include` also disappears, but it seems to me that it is somehow different and may be more of a textual inclusion. Beyond that, it may come down to an implementation choice.

Comment: I feel like it can be done, is there a way to request a feature from the data binding team? :)

Comment: I've not done it, but I am sure you can submit a feature request. My guess is that they have taken such pains to call out the fact that a `ViewStub` is treated differently from a standard `View` that the request would be a hard sell. However, a little searching should lead you to the right place. Your time may be better spent on a work-around.

Answer (score 4):

Passing data to `ViewStub`s is working as expected. You define your namespace and pass the variable in that namespace, and accept it as a regular `<variable>` in your `ViewStub` layout, as follows:

main_layout.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:my-namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="myData" type="com.example.SomeModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/view_stub"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/another_layout"
            my-namespace:data="@{myData}"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

another_layout.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- No need to declare my-namespace here -->
    <data>
        <variable name="data" type="com.example.SomeModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.someValue}" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. I have a very large complex view of a fragment. When adding the fragment to a parent, it is very lag on opening. Using ViewStub and data binding like this is a perfect solution.